# I need to count how many children orgs are assigned to a parent org in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new to the MongoDB world. I'm trying to figure out how to count the number of children organizations assigned to a parent organization. I have documents that have this general structure:

{

```
"_id" : "001",
    "parentOrganization" : {
    "organizationId" : "pOrg1"
    },
"childOrganization" : {
    "organizationId" : "cOrg1"
    }
```

},

{

```
"_id" : "002",
    "parentOrganization" : {
    "organizationId" : "pOrg1"
    },
"childOrganization" : {
    "organizationId" : "cOrg2"
    }
```

},

{

```
"_id" : "003",
    "parentOrganization" : {
    "organizationId" : "pOrg2"
    },
"childOrganization" : {
    "organizationId" : "cOrg3"
    }
```

}

Each document has a parentOrganization with an associated childOrganization. There may be multiple documents with the same parentOrganization, but different childOrganizations. There may also be multiple documents with the same parent/child relationship. Additionally, there may even be a case where a child org may associate with multiple parent orgs.

I'm trying to group by parentOrganization and then count the number of unique childOrganization's associated with each parentOrganization, as well as display the unique id's.

I have tried using an aggregation framework with $match and $group, but I'm still not getting into the child organization parts to count them. Here is what I'm currently attempting:

var s1 = {$match: {"parentOrganization.organizationId": {$exists: true}}};

var s2 = {$group: {_id: "$parentOrganization.organizationId", count: {$sum: "$childOrganization.organizationId"}}};

db.collection.aggregate(s1, s2);

My results are returning the parentOrganization, but my $sum is not returning the number of associated childOrganizations:

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "pOrg1",
    "count" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "pOrg2",
    "count" : 0
}

I get the feeling it is a bit more complicated than my limited knowledge has access to at this time. What details am I missing in this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$sum` is referencing the `childOrganization.organizationId` value, which is a string.  When `$sum` references a string, it will return the value 0.

I was a unsure of exactly what you were asking for, but I believe that these aggregations can help you on your way.

This will return a count of documents groups by the `parentOrganization.organizationId`

```
db.collection.aggregate({$group: {"_id":"$parentOrganization.organizationId", "count": {"$sum": 1}}})
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : "pOrg2", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "pOrg1", "count" : 2 }
```

This will return a count of unique parent/child organizations:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {$group: {"_id": {"parentOrganization": "$parentOrganization.organizationId", "childOrganization": "$childOrganization.organizationId"}, "count":{$sum:1}}})
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : { "parentOrganization" : "pOrg2", "childOrganization" : "cOrg3" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "parentOrganization" : "pOrg1", "childOrganization" : "cOrg2" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "parentOrganization" : "pOrg1", "childOrganization" : "cOrg1" }, "count" : 1 }
```

This will return a count of unique child organizations and get the set of unique child organizations as well using [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/).  One caveat of using `$addToSet` is that the MongoDB 16MB limit on document size still holds.  This means that if your collection is large enough such that the size of the set will make one document greater than 16MB, the command will fail.  The first `$group` will create a set of child organizations grouped by parent organization.  The `$project` is used simply to add the total size of the set to the result.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {"_id" : "$parentOrganization.organizationId", "childOrgs" : { "$addToSet" : "$childOrganization.organizationId"}}},
  {$project: {"_id" : "$_id", "uniqueChildOrgsCount": {"$size" : "$childOrgs"}, "uniqueChildOrgs": "$childOrgs"}}])
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : "pOrg2", "uniqueChildOrgsCount" : 1, "uniqueChildOrgs" : [ "cOrg3" ]}
{ "_id" : "pOrg1", "uniqueChildOrgsCount" : 2, "uniqueChildOrgs" : [ "cOrg2", "cOrg1" ]}
```

During these aggregations, I left out the `$match` statement you included for simplicity, but you could add that back as well.